# how to use multiple variables multiple times without getting them mixed up

Tags: javascript

On the Code here i am trying to get secondGLow be used twice without changing it entrirely.

My Example is

```
(a - b) / 10 * 2 + b = (secondGHigh - secondGLow)/10 * 2 + secondGLow
```

**this is wrong**. the right answer should be 12

```
20 - 10 / 10 * 2 + 10 = 210
```

```js
function calc() {
  var secondGLow = document.getElementById("secondGLow").value,
    secondGHigh = document.getElementById('secondGHigh').value;
  var secondEquation = ((secondGHigh - secondGLow) / 10 * 2 + secondGLow);

  document.getElementById('2ndGear').innerHTML = "2nd Gear: " + secondEquation;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="secondGLow" placeholder="Enter low gear value here">
<input type="number" id="secondGHigh" placeholder="Enter high gear value here">
<button onclick="calc()">calc</button>
<br />
<br />
<label id="2ndGear"></label>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `secondGLow` and `secondGHigh` are strings. If you want to perform a mathematical calculation you'll have to convert those to numbers, otherwise `+` will perform string concatenation.

Try this:

```
var secondGLow = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondGLow").value),
secondGHigh = parseInt(document.getElementById('secondGHigh').value);
```

Comment: Thank you! been having this problem a long while now